# Program prints cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, class

I want to create a program about dogs that use 2 arguments (name and age) and prints the result.I have created 2 java folders , one of them includes arguments and prints the result , inside of the second I just print the arguments and run the first.

First java file

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Dog new_item = new Dog("Peter" , 213123);
    new_item.speak();

}
```

Second java file

```
public class Classes_2 {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Dog(String name , int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("So I think my name is " + this.name + " and my age is " + this.age);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the `Dog` class?

Answer (score 3):

`public class Classes_2 {` should be `public class Dog {` (and the file that contains it should be named `Dog.java`). You can't put a `Dog` constructor in a class that isn't named `Dog`.

Comment: *"and the file that contains it should be named `Dog.java`"* Or you could create a file `Main.java`, create a public `Main` class and use the package modifier for the `Dog` class  where `Main` contains the main method which would work well in simple programs like these :>

Answer (score 0):

> *"Program prints cannot be resolved to a type error ..."*

This is because the class is named *Classes_2*, rather than *Dog*.

If you change this, it runs.  Here is the output.

```
So I think my name is Peter and my age is 213123
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on creating *class* objects.

- *[Lesson: Classes and Objects (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)*